# How can I get the title of a form element in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

For example, in the registration form, there is "Username" and the text field for it which has the input type="text" name="name" ....

I need to know how can I get the title from the input field's name.

I'm expecting a function like:

```
$title = get_title_for_element('name');
```

Result:

```
assert($title == 'Username'); // is true
```

Is there something like this in Drupal?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about unit testing here. Are you trying to unit test a form in paticular or drupals form handling process?

Comment: You should really add in which context you want to do this. If you have the form array available, it's not hard to see the title and other attributes.

Comment: The context I'm using it is that I want to include the field title in the error message that shows up to the user.

That is, I dont want to have an error message like "Should not contain spaces", but rather "Username, should not contain spaces" is more correct. This is why I need to figure out the title.

Comment: I know that such data exists in the $form array variable, but it is hectic to understand the $form data structure and extract the correct data from it, specially when different input elements belong to different group names.

Comment: Where are you doing the validation?

Comment: function kacst_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    $form['#validate'][] = 'kacst_user_register_validate';
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways as I see it. Let's create a module called *mycustomvalidation.module* (remember to create the *mycustomvalidation.info* file also).

**Note:** The code below has not been tested, so you might have to do some minor adjustments. This is Drupal 6.x code by the way.

#### 1) Using `hook_user()`

What you need is a custom module containing your own implementation of `hook_user()` http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_user/6.

```
<?php
function mycustomvalidation_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'validate') {
    // Checking for an empty 'profile_fullname' field here, but you should adjust it to your needs.
    if ($edit['profile_fullname'] != '') {
      form_set_error('profile_fullname', t("Field 'Fullname' must not be empty."));
    }
  }
}
?>
```

#### 2) Using `form_alter()` and a custom validation function

Personally, I would go for this option because I find it cleaner and more "correct". We're adding a custom validation function to our profile field here.

```
<?php
function mycustomvalidation_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check if we are loading 'user_register' or 'user_edit' forms.
  if ($form_id == 'user_register' || $form_id == 'user_edit') {
    // Add a custom validation function to the element.
    $form['User information']['profile_fullname']['#element_validate'] = array('mycustomvalidation_profile_fullname_validate');
  }
}

function mycustomvalidation_profile_fullname_validate($field) {
  // Checking for an empty 'profile_fullname' field here, but you should adjust it to your needs.
  if ($field['#value'] != '') {
    form_set_error('profile_fullname', t("Field %title must not be empty.", array('%title' => $field['#title']));
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the form and the form state variables available to your validation function. You should use [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/form_set_error/6) to set the error.

There is no function that I am aware of which will map from the values array to the form array. But it is not dificult to work it out. Understanding the form data structure is one of the key skills you need when building drupal.

In this case the form in question is generated (in a roundabout way) by [user_edit_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_edit_form/6), you can see the data structure in there. 
 `$form['account']['name']` is the username field. and the array key for the title is `'#title'` as it will be in most cases for form elements.

Comment: The above still doesn't work for me.

I've added extra fields to the registration form using the Administer -> User Management -> Profiles from Drupal.

The names are profile_fullname, profile_mobile_no, profile_landline, profile_occupation.

I cant find them in the $form array under the ['account'] key, they are somewhere else, inside ['#uid']['User Information']['profile_fullname'].

See, the problem is I need a consistent function to extract what I need based on the input element name.